# Moving selected items between 2 JList with add/remove buttons using AbstractListModel

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm brand new to programming. It seems the more I research the more I confuse myself, I have to be over thinking what needs to be done. abstract list model is what is needed to make the `Jlist` work properly. I need to know what is right/wrong. where do I put `getselectedvalues()`, if it even needs to be used?

```
JList Left_list = new JList();
    Left_list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        }
    });
    Left_list.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    Left_list.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {
        String[] values = new String[] {"Case", "Motherboard", "CPU", "RAM", "GPU", "HDD", "PSU"};
        public int getSize() {
            return values.length;
        }
        public Object getElementAt(int index) {
            return values[index];
        }
    });
    Left_list.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2, true));
    Left_list.setBounds(10, 11, 146, 218);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Left_list);

    JList Right_list = new JList();
    Right_list.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {
        String[] values = new String[] {};
        public int getSize() {
            return values.length;
        }
        public Object getElementAt(int index) {
            return values[index];
        }
    });
    Right_list.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2, true));
    Right_list.setBounds(278, 16, 146, 213);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Right_list);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Add>>");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(166, 91, 102, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("<<Remove");
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });
    btnNewButton_1.setBounds(166, 125, 102, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);
```

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: is the layout stopping me from getting selected items from one list to the other?

Comment: No, but it will blow up you face and make life miserable for you...

Answer (score 2):

What I would recommend, is using a `DefaultListModel` instead, as it provides the ability to mutate the `ListModel`

```
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
for (String item : new String[] {"Case", "Motherboard", "CPU", "RAM", "GPU", "HDD", "PSU"}) {
    model.addElement(item);
}
JList<String> Left_list= new JList<>();
Left_list.setModel(model);
//...

JList<String> Right_list = new JList<>(new DefaultListModel<String>());
//...

btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        List<String> selected = Left_list.getSelectedValuesList();
        DefaultListModel<String> left = Left_list.getModel();
        DefaultListModel<String> right = Right_list.getModel();
        for (String item : selected) {
            left.removeElement(item);
            right.addElement(item);
        }
    }
});
//...
JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("<<Remove");
btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        List<String> selected = Right_list.getSelectedValuesList();
        DefaultListModel<String> left = Left_list.getModel();
        DefaultListModel<String> right = Right_list.getModel();
        for (String item : selected) {
            right.removeElement(item);
            left.addElement(item);
        }
    }
});
```

You may need to make `Left_list` and `Right_list` instance fields in order for the `ActionListener`s to access them.

While writing the example, I thought it would be easy to write a simple method which could move data from one list to another, something like `protected void move(List<String> items, DefaultListModel from, DefaultListModel to)`, which means you could simply use `move(Left_list.getSelectedValuesList(), Left_list.getModel(), Right_list.getModel())` or `move(Right_list.getSelectedValuesList(), Right_list.getModel(), Left_list.getModel())` to move content about and reduce the code duplication...

`JList`s are really suppose to be displayed in `JScrollPane`s, this allows the list to be much longer/wider than the available space on the screen

Take a look at

- [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
- [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)
- [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others
- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

...for more details